# Change the interval in which SharePoint and Outlook sync their tasks?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, outlook, task-list, sync

SharePoint only syncs with Outlook tasks in intervals and for our company it is better if we can minimize the time between each sync. Is there a way to do that in SharePoint? And how?

Answer (score 0):

```
stsadm -o setproperty –propertyname <property name> -propertyvalue <property value>
```

So in this case, to set to 0 minutes:

```
STSADM -o setproperty - propertyname "min-time-between-syncs" - propertyvalue "0"
```

More information here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/akashb/2013/04/05/all-i-know-about-outlook-20102013-and-sharepoint-synchronization/